# Expectation of stopping time of a Markov process with drift

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

As a follow-up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2107249/expectation-stopped-brownian-motion-with-drift), for a Markov process $X_t$ with drift $u>0$ and variance $\sigma^2$, the Laplace transform of the stopping time $T=inf\{t: X_t = a >0\}$ is

$$
\mathbb{E}[\exp(-\lambda T)]
 = \exp\left(-a* \frac{\sqrt{u^2 + 2\sigma^2\lambda} - u}{\sigma^2}\right)
$$

If taking derivative and let $\lambda = 0$, I will get $E[T] = a/u$, which is independent of $\sigma^2$. Is this right?

Comment: What do you mean general Markov process like this? Do you mean a diffusion process given by $dX_t=\mu dt + \sigma dB_t$?

Comment: Also what is this $u$, is it supposed to be $\mu$?

Comment: What I have in mind is $X_t = ut + \sigma B_t$ where $B_t$ is a standard Brownian motion. Is this the same process as your notation?

Comment: Yes. I would not describe this as a "general Markov process". It is a diffusion process.

Comment: Ah, okay. Is the expectation right?

Comment: The end result is right (I checked with a different method). I don't know about the Laplace transform result offhand.